# PhoneGap shows the default icon instead of my icon

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

My `config.xml`, `index.html`, and my icons are all in root, but PhoneGap doesn't show my icon. It shows the default PhoneGap build-in icon.

Here is my config.xml (I removed `www/` from `src` but it still doesn't show up):

```
<icon src="www/icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="www/icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="www/icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="www/icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="www/icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="www/icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="www/icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="www/icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="www/icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="www/icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="www/icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="www/icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="www/icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="www/icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put all your icons in the root `www` folder. Create a subfolder for the resources, let's say `res` and then create a subfolder for the icons, say `icon` (because you can have other resources like splash screen). Finally, create a subfolder for each platform (e.g. `ios`, `android`). Now, in `config.xml`, don't use the old `gap:platform="ios"`. Instead, group all your icons by platform:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/splash/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
</platform>
```